# How to show firestore all document fields on PaginatedDataTable or datatable as streambuilder on flutter web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am able to show normal text fields on PaginatedDataTable. But I want to show my Firestore fields on PaginatedDataTable as stream builder method. I have searched on internet but I could not find relevant to my requirement.
How to get firestore data in to PaginatedDataTable source. Or is there any other way Please let me know. Looking for solution and It is very useful  if there is get on tapeable row or selectable row also. I want to fetch data from firestore only not from firebase auth. And I have named the firestore collection name as "users". it my be different also
Need help how to do this? if it is not possible in PaginatedDataTable, DataTable also fine.

Below is my example Firestore collection and document structure:

```
firestore collection name: users

documentID1-
    email: 'email1'
    name : 'name1'
    role : 'role1'
    uid  : 'uid1'

documentID2-
    email: 'email2'
    name : 'name2'
    role : 'role2'
    uid  : 'uid2'
```

(more than 20 documents)

Below is my example code which is normally able to show with normal text:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AdminDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const AdminDashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AdminDashboardState createState() => _AdminDashboardState();
}

class _AdminDashboardState extends State<AdminDashboard> {
  final DataTableSource _allUsers = UsersData();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          header: const Text("Header Text"),
          rowsPerPage: 9,
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Uid')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Email')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Role'))
          ],
          source: _allUsers,
        ),


      ),
    );
  }
}

class UsersData extends DataTableSource {
  //final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allUsers = [{}];
  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      index: index,
      cells: [
        DataCell(Text('row #$index')),
        DataCell(Text('name #$index')),
        DataCell(Text('name #$index')),
        DataCell(Text('name #$index')),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => 9;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

Please find below image of Errors after edited as per @xBurnsed Answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had the chance to test this but something like the following should point you to the right direction:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    List<User> users;
    return StreamBuilder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("[YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap) {
            users = snap.data.docs.map((e) => User.fromMap(e.data)).toList();
            final DataTableSource _allUsers = UsersData(users);
            if(snap.hasData){
                return PaginatedDataTable(
                  header: const Text("Header Text"),
                  rowsPerPage: 9,
                  columns: const [
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Uid')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Email')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Role'))
                  ],
                  source: _allUsers,
                );
            }
            else{
                return new Text('No data...');
            }
    });
}


class UsersData extends DataTableSource {
  final List<User> users;

  UsersData(this.users);
  
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
     return DataRow.byIndex(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(users[index].uid)),
      DataCell(Text(users[index].name)),
      DataCell(Text(users[index].email)),
      DataCell(Text(users[index].role)),
    ], index: index);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => 9;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

You will have to create your User class for this to work tho so you are able to populate your source, if you don't want to, you can always use a `List<DataRow>` in your DataTableSource instead of a `List<User>` and manually map each cell.

Comment: I have edited your referenced answer but showing some errors on code  I have added the image on my Question. Please find.

Comment: @user3030327 For your first error I edited my code. For the following errors I already stated in my solution that you are going to need to create an User class with its fields. Don't just copy paste, try to understand whats going on, read the error messages and work from there.

Comment: My mistake, I have changed from 'documents ' to 'docs'. But added the before image. After chanced it showing the error ""a value of type list dynamic cannot be assigned to a variable of type list<User>"" changed error image also. I am stuck with still first error.

Comment: @user3030327 Have you created your User class with the required fields?

Comment: Not yet, First I am tiring to get all data in to list as users  variable. Searching..

Comment: "List<User> users;" Showing error.  as  """The name 'User' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'User'."""

Comment: You will not be able to create "User" variables if the "User" class doesn't exist first. Have you created the "User" class?

Comment: @mgoya User class Not created. But still I am in confuse, Why need user class. Actually I want to fetch  data from firestore only not from firebase auth. And I have named the firestore collection name as "users". it my be different also.

Comment: @mgoya . If User class should be there! and what should be there in User class, Can you give me any example.

Comment: @mgoya : I have create class like this : '''class User {
  
  late String name;

  late String email;

  late String role;

  late String uid;

  static fromMap(Object? Function() data) {}
}''' But showing as **Expected a value of type 'User', but got one of type 'Null'**

Comment: @user3030327 This seems like a new question to me. The answer to the original question is to create the object, but how to create object could be a new question, which should include what have you tried to solve the issue yourself. Having such long conversations in comments do not help the community.

Comment: @jofre Thank you, And I have asked new question.